# updating the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, updates

i have 2 forms and dont know how to update the datagridview, if some can simply guide me please. form1 is as follows:

```
public partial class frmBooking : Form
{
    //instance of sqlConnection created           
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=....");


    public frmBooking()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //sets the  time selecter to a time format and selects the hours and mins only in 24 hour format.
        TimeOfBooking.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";
        TimeOfBooking.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

        //combo box get data from database and updates when new customer is added 
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
        }

        NameOfCustomer.Items.Clear();

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT GroupName FROM Customer ORDER BY GroupName ASC", con);

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                NameOfCustomer.Items.Add(dr["GroupName"]);
            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }


        //ends here
    }

      //sets the facility name so its copied from the previous(facility to be booked) form into the Facility text box
    public void setFacility(string new_facility)
    {
        Facility.Text = new_facility;
    }

    //sets the date so its copied from the previous(facility to be booked) form into the date text box
    public void setDate(string new_date)
    {
        Date.Text = new_date;
    }


    //adding a new customer button, redirects user to the add customer page
    private void btnAddCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmNewCustomer newCust = new frmNewCustomer();
        newCust.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    //cancel button will redirect the user to the main page
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
        frm3.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void frmBooking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet.Customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.Customer);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet.Customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.Customer);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet.Customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.Customer);

    }

    private void lblBookingForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //validation - if any of the mandotory fields are empty an error message will apear next to the text box
        if (Facility.Text == "")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Facility, Date, Name Of Customer, Time Of Booking and Hours");
            errorFacility.SetError(Facility, "Enter A Facility To Book");
        }
        else if (Date.Text == "")
        {
            errorDate.SetError(Date, "Enter A Valid Date");
        }
        else if (NameOfCustomer.Text == "")
        {
            errorCust.SetError(NameOfCustomer, "Enter A Customer To Book");
        }
        else if (TimeOfBooking.Text == "")
        {
            errorTime.SetError(TimeOfBooking, "Enter A Time To Book");
        }
        else if (Hours.Text == "")
        {
            errorHours.SetError(Hours, "Enter The Hours To Book");
        }

        //so if there isnt no error in the fields itll go on and add the data in to the database.
        else
        {

        //instance of sqlConnection            
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=...");

        //instance of sqlCommand
        String query =
            "INSERT INTO [Booking] values ('"
            + Facility.Text
            + "', '" + Date.Text
            + "', '" + NameOfCustomer.Text
            + "', '" + TimeOfBooking.Text
            + "', '" + Hours.Text
            + "', '" + Paid.Text
            + "', '" + Notes.Text
            + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        //query executed correcty or not
        con.Close();

           MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Booked");

           Form3 mainPage = new Form3();
           mainPage.Show();
           this.Close();
        } 
    }
    }}
```

this is the form i am using to add a Booking.
The second form i have is the one with the datagridview, which i want to update when the booking is made the code for that is as follows:

```
        public partial class frmViewBookings : Form
        {
            public frmViewBookings()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form3 mainpage = new Form3();
                mainpage.Show();
                this.Close();
            }

            private void frmViewBookings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet1.Booking' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.bookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet1.Booking);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll try again. We need to see where you create and show your frmViewBookings Form. Can you provide that code?

Comment: i have split it up , the top is my frmBooking form and the bottom frmViewBooking form... this is all i have so far

Comment: I understand that, but somewhere you have a line of code that is similar to: frmViewBookings newFrmViewBookings = new frmViewBookings(); newFrmViewBookings.Show(); can you show us where you do that?

Comment: i do not have this, i had simply dragged the datagridview from the toolbox, and changed the data source to match that of the booking table, which displays the data stored in the table and only updates when the program is shut down an run again,

Comment: Then how does frmViewBookings get displayed to the user??? You aren't providing enough information for anyone to help you solve the problem.

Comment: you tell me? lol like i said everything works fine on the program apart from displaying the data unless i go off the program and run it again. but i can add data to the actual database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27030/discussion-between-rob-and-bandaa)

Answer (score 0):

To display data on your datagrid you would have to set it's Datasource first which you would do like this

`datagridview1.Datasource = this.usersDataSet1.Booking.DefaultView`

Whenever you want to refresh it you will just have to fill your tableadapter again and set your gridview's datasource to it.

(Create a seperate method to load datagridview)